# Getting "The CSRF tokens do not match" when using nginx

Tags: nginx, flask, cookies, csrf

When app is running without nginx then Flask forms work fine. But when I use NGINX then i get "**{'csrf_token': ['The CSRF tokens do not match.']}**" error every time I try to submit the form.
What could be an issue?
I have tried:

- to clear all the cookies from the browser.
- submit the form while accessing an app in incognito mode.
- reviewed all of the forums in stackoverflow that are related with this issue.

Nothing helped. What could be an issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer in this article: https://nickjanetakis.com/blog/fix-missing-csrf-token-issues-with-flask

Appearantly Flask does not loke (cookie likewise) to use IP addresses as SERVER_NAME parameter. So at least set it to localhost.domain or something similar and everything will be ok :)